# Can't get Value in a SelectListItem to be read as a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a drop down list that combines the Responsibility and Level into one line within the list. However, I want them saving into their own columns within the SQl database so I have used the identity column from that table Responsibility_Key.

Here is my code:

```
              public ActionResult Delegate(string Responsibility, string Responsibility_Key, string ADUserName, string Level, string submit)
    {
        var Dgates = cc_Db.Dim_Responsibility
          .Select(s => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = s.Responsibility_Key.ToString(),
              Text = s.Responsibility + " - " + s.Level
          });
       ViewBag.Responsibility = new SelectList(Dgates, "Value", "Text");

        return View();
    }
```

I have tried multiple different ways of converting to a string as well as using .AsNumerable and IENumerable but with no success.

The error I keep getting is 
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's the error you're getting?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess (as you confirmed with your edit) is that you are using some kind of ORM, (e.g.) entity framework, and that it can't translate ToString() to SQL

First fetch an anonymous ienumerable, then tolist, e.g.

```
var Dgates = cc_Db.Dim_Responsibility.Select(new{
              Value = s.Responsibility_Key,
              Text = s.Responsibility + " - " + s.Level
}).ToList().Select(a => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = a.Value.ToString(),
              Text = a.Text
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly thanks! The drop down list now populates with both variables. However, I am now getting an error when trying to save the data because the variables Level isn't being saved. I'm presuming this is because we combined it with Responsibility and it hasn't been split back into the original variables before it gets saved?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var Dgates = cc_Db.Dim_Responsibility
        .Select(s => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = s.Responsibility_Key.ToString(),
              Text = s.Responsibility + " - " + s.Level
          }).ToList();
```

This will make `Dgates` a `List<SelectListItem>` which should satisfy `new SelectList(Dgates, "Value", "Text");`